# Jupyter Notebook running servers list - ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to get the list of running servers using the command-line:

```
jupyter notebook list
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/py27/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1571, in start
    super(NotebookApp, self).start()
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 255, in start
    self.subapp.start()
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 483, in start
    serverinfo_list = list(list_running_servers(self.runtime_dir))
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1667, in list_running_servers
    info = json.load(f)
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/sarah/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

How to correct it? I don't understand the reason.

Answer (score 8):

The logic for determining running notebook servers relies on iterating over all files in runtime-dir with prefix "nbserver-" and trying to load as JSON. Therefore, a malformed file in this folder may be causing the JSON error. Solved this by deleting all files under the Jupyter runtime-dir:

```bash
$ jupyter --runtime-dir
/home/user/.local/share/jupyter/runtime
$ cd $(jupyter --runtime-dir) && rm *
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Worked for me. I'll add you don't necessarily need to remove everything. My directory had old files in it which were the cause of the problem I left remaining the file that was related to my active session.

Comment: Would upvote 10 more times if I could.  This issue was plaguing me for more than a year until I found this answer.